# Azure functions with B2C Authentication

Tags: azure, function, authentication

I'm stuck trying some basic stuff.
I want to secure Azure functions with an Azure B2C login.
However I followed 7 (or more) tutorials and step by step guides but none of that are working
like https://codemilltech.com/adding-azure-ad-b2c-authentication-to-azure-functions/

My problem is as soon as the azure function is protected and I want to call it in the browser, the login appears just like expected. But after the login the azure function does not seem to be called. Instead a "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." with no further information is displayed.

Additional Info:
*) All tutorials I looked at seemed kind of outdated because the UI in Azure looks slightly different for me than in the images provided but notthing serious.
*) The Userflow is v2 (I also tried v1 without effect)

Comment: Azure Functions works different than Web App. You need to get the token acquired from Azure AD B2C and pass it in the http Authorization Header. This is why it's not working when  calling it from the browser.

Comment: Did you read the link provided? "Adding azure ad b2c authenticaton to azure functions" seems pretty azure function spezific to me.

I also tried getting the token and make the call with postman without any effect I always geht an Unauthorized response message.

Comment: I finally found the solution.
No tutorial mentioned that you have to add the ApplicationId of the application that is used to get the token into the "Allowed token audiences". After that the Error is gone an you can access the service like expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
No tutorial I looked into mentioned that you have to add the ApplicationId of the application that is used to get the token into the "Allowed token audiences" section in the advanced AD configuration.
After that the Error is gone an you can access the service like expected.
[Configuration Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g03x6.png)

Comment: Please provide more details of this for this to be useful.